# How to solve a limit that can be factored but doesn't help?

Tags: limits

I saw examples that can be factored, eliminating the part that causes the indetermination, none of this type. The other option is by rationalize but dont know how to apply it here.

$$\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{2x^2+7x+5}{x^2-16}$$
I tried by factoring, doesn't help
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(2x+5)(x+1)}{(x-4)(x+4)} \\$$

**UPDATE**: I make a mistake, the numerator is ${2x^2+7x+5}$ not ${x^2+7x+5}$, really sorry.

Comment: To make life easier, let $x=4+y$. It gives  $\frac{y^2+15 y+49}{y^2+8 y}$ and now $y\to 0$

Comment: Think about the values of the numerator and the denominator when $x$ is very close to 4, say $4.01$.

Comment: Your factorization for the $x^2+7x+5$ term seems not correct, even if it is not the main issue with the resolution.

Comment: @user You're right sorry, I updated, it should be $2x^2+7x+5$

Comment: @user2495207 Thanks, in any case this is not the main issue for the resolution.

Comment: @PCMSE I hastened to replay, it's not 0/0, thanks

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Your limit is in the form

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{2x^2+7x+5}{(x-4)(x+4)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(2x+5)(x+1)}{(x+4)}\cdot \lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{1}{x-4}$$

with

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(2x+5)(x+1)}{(x+4)} =\frac{65}{8}$$

then all boils down in that one

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{1}{x-4} $$